# Quadrilateral bisecting - GEOMETRY

Tags: geometry

Hey guys this was from my textbook:

The diagonal MO of a quadrilateral MNOP, bisects ∠ NOP and ∠ PMN. Prove that the other diagonal NP is perpendicular to MO.

I feel as if this questions requires congruent triangles, however I'm not 100% sure. I'm not sure where to go from here. I'd appreciate hints but not the straight-up answer because I want to work it out by myself.

Comment: Have you tried using vector geometry?

Answer (score 0):

Because $MO$ bisects $∠ NOP$, $∠ MOP = ∠ MON$.

Because $MO$ bisects $∠ PMN$, $∠ PMO = ∠ NMO$.

Because of [ASA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)#Determining_congruence) theorem => $\Delta MPO \cong \Delta MNO $=> $PO = ON$

Because of [symmetry in isosceles triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_triangle#Symmetry) => $OM \bot PN$